# How to include custom block to phtml file

Tags: magento2.4.1, magento-2-commerce

I have created a block for getting wishlist items, after that i need this list to my custom phtml file,

my block :

app\code\vendor\path\Block\WishlistProducts.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Path\Block;
    
    use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
    use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
    use Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item\CollectionFactory as WishlistCollectionFactory;
    use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
    
    
    class WishlistProducts extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
    {
        protected $_wishlistCollectionFactory;
        protected $_customerSession;
        protected $_productCollectionFactory;
    
        public function __construct(Context $context,
            CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
            WishlistCollectionFactory $wishlistCollectionFactory,
            Session $customerSessio
        ) {
            $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
            $this->_wishlistCollectionFactory = $wishlistCollectionFactory;
            $this->_customerSession = $customerSessio;
        }
        
        public function getWishlistProductCollection()
        {
            $collection = [];
            if ($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
                $wishlist = $this->_wishlistCollectionFactory->create()
                    ->addCustomerIdFilter($this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getId());
    
                $productIds = null;
                foreach ($wishlist as $product) {
                    $productIds[] = $product->getProductId();
                }
                
                $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()->addIdFilter($productIds);
                $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)->addStoreFilter($this->getStoreId());
            }
            return $collection;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

app\code\vendor\path\view\frontend\wishlistitems.phtml

for testing:

```
<?Php
echo("hello");
?>
```

How to get this on my custom phtml DropdownDialog widget

app\design\frontend\Zero\my_theme\Magento_Theme\templates\location_link.phtml

```
<div class="wishlist minicart-wrapper" data-block="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="action" data-trigger="trigger">
        <img class="wishlist-img" src='<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/Group_5288.png'); ?>' alt="Logo">
    </a>
</div>

<div class="block block-minicart"
     data-mage-init='{
        "dropdownDialog": {
            "appendTo": "[data-block=dropdown]",
            "triggerTarget":"[data-trigger=trigger]",
            "timeout": 2000,
            "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
            "closeOnEscape": true,
            "autoOpen": false,
            "triggerClass": "active",
            "parentClass": "active",
            "buttons": []
        }
     }'>
    <div id="minicart-content-wrapper">

                    <?php 
                    include($block->getTemplateFile('vendor_path::wishlistitems.phtml')) 
                    ?>                 
    </div>
</div>
```

page error, if i add

```
 <p>hi</p>  // when i click my icon hi message working
```

What is the proper way to call my block into phtml file?

**or**

FYI - How to get this https://i.stack.imgur.com/S07Za.png into my custom phtml file DropdownDialog widget

Comment: <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Vendor\Path\Block\WishlistProducts")->setTemplate("vendor_path::wishlistitems.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>

Comment: You can call like above in phtml file

Comment: <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Vendor\Path\Block\WishlistProducts")->setTemplate("My_Module::wishlistitems.phtml")->toHtml(); ?> i want to add the block inside the DropdownDialog widget, if user click my icon the responce should view on dropdown DropdownDialog

Comment: can u pls join the chat bro https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120695/how-to-include-custom-block-to-phtml-file

Comment: You need to call it under div "<div id="minicart-content-wrapper">"

Comment: yes, i call under <div id="minicart-content-wrapper">, still not working can u pls join the chat

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120695/how-to-include-custom-block-to-phtml-file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120696/discussion-between-zus-and-zealousweb).

Comment: @ZealousWeb How to test my block code working or not, still its not return any value, can u pls help me on this, thanks.

Comment: Can you pls help me

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120696/discussion-between-zus-and-zealousweb

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use block in .phtml file as:
echo $block->myfunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :-**

```
<?php
$blockObj= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('vendor\path\Block\WishlistProducts');
 echo $blockObj->myfunction();
?>
```